# the abbility to orbit has suddenly stopped working

Tags: 3d-view

hi all im new here and new to blender, well i was 2 months ago lol

i was using blender today and the orbit stopped working. ive tried changing it from the middle mouse to a different key and it is still not working. it periodically starts to work and then stops. i restarted my computer and the problem is still there. it happened after i applied a sub surface modifier  to something. i also tried loading it up and deleting everything it gives you as standard like the cube and light etc but it still wont work. everything els is fine like the the zoom etc and i even tried to do a render of another model and it worked as fast as always. it seems to be just the orbit that has stopped. is there a fix or am i best off un-installing and reinstalling. i was right in the middle of doing a basics of sculpting course too

im sure like everything in blender ive probably pressed something i shouldnt have. thanks in advance

Comment: Try File → Defaults → Load factory settings. You may accidentally overwrite some hotkeys

Comment: thank you i'll try that

Comment: tried that and still the same issue issue

Comment: Well, try to change mouse then. Maybe it is a hardware problem.